# WinAVR and native Windows console apps

Tags: file, gcc, makefile, winavr

I'm not that experienced with C, but I've been happily hacking firmware on some hobby projects using WinAVR. I'm visually impaired so I prefer using make files and the command line, instead of a graphically confusing IDE.

Sometimes I want to thrash out an algorithm at the Windows console prompt, with a few printf statements to show me what's happening.  But I don't want to install a native Windows variant of GCC and mess up my working WinAVR installation.

What's the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

i think http://www.cygwin.com/ would be a great choice.. you can install cygwin and then install gcc install cygwin. you can have all the unix tools if you want

Comment: Installing cygwin is straightforward http://cygwin.com/install.html and installing http://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~aamodt/ece242/cygwin.html is also click of some buttons. Though linux/unix will be addon on using additional stuff,its not a mandatory . after installation is complete its more of a command line utility